# Docker container remaps localhost from 127.0.0.1 to my computer's IP address

Tags: docker, networking

I am running a Docker container in the background on port 8000. I am also running a Django app on port 8000. Weirdly enough, *both* work — I can access the Docker app at `localhost:8000`, and the Django app at `127.0.0.1:8000`.

I did some digging, and I believe that Docker has somehow remapped localhost to point to my computer's IP address instead of to the loopback address of `127.0.0.1`. This is confirmed because other devices on my network can access the Docker app on my computer through `ip_address:8000`, and when I kill the container, `localhost:8000` reverts to serving me my Django app.

**My question is, how has docker done this and why?**

More information:

- Running `docker ps` shows the port mapping of `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp` as expected, which I believe just means that my computer's port 8000 is mapped to the container's 8000.
- There is nothing my `/etc/hosts` or `/private/etc/hosts` file to explain this behavior.
- While my wifi is on, both `localhost:8000` and `ip_address:8000` serve the container, but when I disconnect my internet, `ip_address:8000` stops serving the container. If Docker were remapping localhost --> device IP address, wouldn't `localhost:8000` stop working too?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You have the best username on SO.